# Warning/Error message "The ) is expected" - Functional Attribute - GeoMedia Desktop

Tags: error, fields-attributes, expression, geomedia

[image: Error in the Expression]

So the problem, is when I write my Expression on the Functional Attribute window in GeoMedia Pro, it gives me a warning message indicates that the ")" is expected;

The expression is : `ROUND(AREA(Input.Shape, TrueMeas, SquareMile), 2)`

Comment: can you narrow it down by trying just AREA(Input.Shape, TrueMeas, SquareMile)?

Comment: **Solution** : *Need to replace* ',' with ';' Thanks @iant